# Efficiently Mowing Grass with Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, image-processing, computational-geometry, animation, simulation

Recently, I was mowing my yard and was thinking about how to use the least amount of time/fuel and how to simulate.

Mowing a yard that is shaped as a convex polygon is not difficult, you can just make a spiral. So,the code:

```
outMostPolygon = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 7}];
mowerWidth = 0.03;
tracks = Table[
   outMostPolygon // 
    ScalingTransform[{1 - i*mowerWidth, 1 - i*mowerWidth}, 
     RegionCentroid[outMostPolygon]],
   {i, 0, Floor[1/mowerWidth]-1 }
   ];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.005],RGBColor[93/255, 189/255, 0]}], FaceForm[RGBColor[124/255, 252/255, 0]], tracks},AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

gives an example image:

[image: Convex polygonal yard whose treads are essentially its straight line skeleton.]

but the problem is most yards have things in them. And the shapes can be concave as well as the yard being concave so the solution is not always a straight line skeleton. And since repeating a point is allowed (we don't care about the aesthetics of the tread lines), FindShortestPath doesn't work or if it can be used it is not straight forward.

Here is a problematic example:

[image: A similar picture above, it is a convex polygon with it's straight line segment skeleton, but it has a random purple concave polygon inside of it.]

that was created by using the code:

```
outMostPolygon = RandomPolygon[{"Convex",  RandomInteger[{3,10}]}];
mowerWidth = 0.03;
tracks = Table[
   outMostPolygon // 
    ScalingTransform[{1 - i*mowerWidth, 1 - i*mowerWidth}, 
     RegionCentroid[outMostPolygon]],
   {i, 0, Floor[1/mowerWidth]-1 }
   ];
pts = RandomPoint[outMostPolygon, RandomInteger[{3,10}]];
centroid = Mean[pts];
sortedPts = SortBy[pts, ArcTan @@ (# - centroid) &];innerPoly = Polygon[sortedPts];
Show[
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.005],RGBColor[93/255, 189/255, 0]}], FaceForm[RGBColor[124/255, 252/255, 0]], tracks},AspectRatio->Automatic],
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{RGBColor[122/255, 55/255, 122/255], Thick}], FaceForm[RGBColor[163/255, 73/255, 164/255]], innerPoly},AspectRatio->Automatic]
]
```

I personally am partial to straight lines only existing and curves and circles don't exist, but if someone wants to throw a curve ball they are welcome to.

Comment: I do not think there is much to compute. The area is always the same so any path that does not cross itself is optimal.

Comment: @azerbajdzan In some instances, can an optimal path be one that does cross itself? If it was discrete points only, the answer would be no. But for the continuous case, I am not sure. Also, dependencies on how the lattice is made, I am not sure all the hamiltonian paths have the same length.

Comment: No, path that crosses itself cannot be optimal, since in such a case some of the area would be mowed more than once which means you waste your fuel, time and also the final path length is larger.

Comment: "Any path that does not cross itself is optimal" only holds if turning is free, but it's not (according to the utility function of fuel and time)

Comment: This is known as the "Lawn Mowing Problem", and finding the optimal route turns out to be NP-hard. [Here's a recent review of the subject,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.01092.pdf) including links to a Jupyter GitHub repository implementing the algorithms.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That articles makes sense why I was having problems thinking about how to solve it. I knew it was going to be NP, not that level though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

This is just starting ideas for arbitrary regions. Perhaps you can improve it.

---

### Version 1

Define concave region with holes, which can be generalizable to arbitrary complexity:

```
eq=x^2/2-y^2<=1&&x^2+y^2/7>1/2&&-3<x<3&&-3<y<3;
R=ImplicitRegion[eq,{x,y}];
RegionPlot[R]
```

[image]

Define a grid that covers the region:

```
grd = Tuples[Range[-30, 30]/10, 2];
```

By adjusting density / number of grid points you can match the width of the mower. Pick those grid points inside the region:

```
grdR=Select[grd,RegionMember[R]];

Graphics[Point[grdR], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Find shortest path:

```
path=grdR[[FindShortestTour[grdR][[2]]]];

Graphics[Line@path]
```

[image]

This path feels like it is something Jack Nicholson would walk with a mower in the 1980 "The Shining" movie. We can try to improve by introducing a penalty into the distance function. By default the the distance function is simply `EuclideanDistance`. But consider the following modification:

```
disF=(1+Abs[CosineDistance[#1+#2,#2-#1]-1]^10)EuclideanDistance[#1,#2]&;
```

It makes preferable the paths orthogonal to radial vectors from the origin with the hope that it would make path more like a gradual spiral. Power `^10` is a tunable parameter you can use to change the path a bit. By using this distance function we get the image shown at the top left:

```
path=grdR[[FindShortestTour[grdR,DistanceFunction->disF][[3]]]];
Graphics[{Line@path,Red,Point[grdR]}]
```

[image]

So why is it not a spiral? My first, perhaps wrong, guess is -- it's due to constraint of `FindShortestTour` giving a **tour** -- meaning close loop. If you could start at the origin and and at the periphery, perhaps the path would be more spiral-like. That's why you can try using `FindHamiltonianPath` via building first a Graph. `FindHamiltonianPath` allows for start and end of the path.

---

### Version 2

I do not have enough computing power to build this one. So this is a toy example. First, build a graph based on a mesh of your region:

```
g = MeshConnectivityGraph[DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 1]]
```

I made it intentionally low-resolution due to computing power limitation. Pick some start and end vertices - one inside and another on outside:

```
In[]:= se = VertexList[g][[{67, 41}]]
Out[]= {{0, 67}, {0, 41}} 

HighlightGraph[g, se, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Find Hamiltonian Path and plot it -- as shown on the top image right. It does look like a spiral. For better results use finer mesh, but `FindHamiltonianPath` might take long time.

```
hami = FindHamiltonianPath[g, Sequence @@ se];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@hami, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Comment: I think a penalty for turns might be something to add too. You generally want long straight paths when mowing a lawn, avoid intricate little wiggles like your top left example has on all the main diagonals. It'd definitely be preferable to avoid those 45° switchbacks that you have along the curves, too; better to follow the curve than zigzag back and forth all along it.

Comment: @Hearth what the code would look like?

Comment: No clue, I'm afraid.